# Table getting stretched vertically

Tags: html, css, html-table, stretch

I'm currently working on a variant of Tic-Tac-Toe that requires boards within boards. I'm not going to post the HTML since it's way too long but the format is:

```
<table id="board">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button or text>
```

Everything's working pretty smoothly but I'm having trouble with the CSS. Initially the board looks like this:
[image]

but then after a few moves it looks like this:
[image]

If you look at the middle table, it has been slightly vertically stretched, due to the difference in size between the buttons and letters, making it look a bit sloppy. Nothing else seems to stretch this way. Here's my CSS:

```
table button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    margin:1px
}
table#board > tr > td > table > tr > td {
    <!--Small cells-->
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
}
table#board > tr > td {
    <!--Big cells-->
    min-height: 120px;
    min-width: 120px;
}
table#board > tr > td > table {
    min-height: 146px;
    min-width: 146px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

If anyone knows how to stop the table from stretching, or how to improve my CSS in general, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I'd use divs instead of tables, but if you're going to use tables, take a look at the line-height property to get control over how much vertical space your letters take up.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Comment: @reidm what you mean by stretch .? can you just provide demo html of your need.?

Comment: You can use absolute positioning of the contents within each table cell. In this way the contents won't mess with the size of the cell at all. You may have to put those absolutely positioned contents inside a <div> with relative positioning, in order for the absolute positioning to be relative to that containing div.

Comment: One way to improve your CSS is to not use HTML comments.

Comment: You should check the sizes of the buttons. a button with a CSS `height` of 40px plus a margin of 1px will take up more space than available in the table cell. (Unless you have changed the `box-sizing` to `border-box`, but I don't see that in your code.)